# Custom Formtastic Control with Multiple Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, input, formtastic

I'm attempting to build a custom control for Formtastic that takes a latitude and a longitude, however, I'm not sure how to go about passing the method names through. Ideally I'd have the following in the semantic_form_for block:

```
f.input :latitude, :longitude, :as => :location
```

I've also tried passing with an array:

```
f.input [:latitude, :longitude], :as => :location
```

But in both cases, this fails - the first on the number of parameters, the second on the first parameter not being a symbol.

Is there any way of passing two methods into #input that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've sorted this out by writing [a plugin for Formtastic](https://codebeef.com/posts/maptastic-now-a-gem/).

I've added a multi_input function that can take any number of parameters and an (optional) options hash. I've also added a map_input type that outputs the map control and JS (framework agnostic).

More details at the above link.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass multiple methods to a single input. What you could do is have an accessor on your model called, uh, `lat_long` or similar, which could return a string or array or whatever in a format which your location_input recognises and knows how handle.

Comment: Thanks Justin (for your answer and Formtastic :D) - I've been thinking about this, and I reckon going through input is probably the wrong thing to do - it breaks encapsulation if the model needs to present specific methods for view stuff. 

As far as I can tell, I'd be better to create a new method in SemanticFormBuilder akin to #input and #commit_button - maybe #multi_input?